# Excel is adding indesired quotes on csv files

Tags: excel, csv, office365

I get a csv file that contains cells with quoted strings.

When I open the csv file using excel and then make a modification on it then save it ,It get double quotes strings.

An example of what cells contains

```
case when table1=1  AND MODELE = "Example" THEN result
```

When I change the containing to

```
case when table1=1  AND MODELE = "Edited" THEN result
```

Then I save and reopen the file I get :

```
case when table1=1  AND MODELE = ""Edited"" THEN result
```

And that get applied on all the file.

How to espace excel from doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

CSV quotes fields that include spaces, like your example value. You would ordinarily use quotes in all CSV fields, and escape the quotes you want to keep with double quotes, like so:

```
"cell 1", "cell 2", "cell with ""escaped"" quotes"
```

Here is a detailed [explanation](http://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php) including specific references to Excel handling.

You cannot control the way Excel exports CSV. You'll need to deal with the quotes before or after the export.

Comment: Theses files are injected to a server so I should not add quotes to it.

Is there a solution to force excel not adding any quotes ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'll have to add a step after the export to remove any undesired quotes.